# oracle sql row count affected by select clause

Tags: sql, oracle

While working on a oracle SQL , noticed that adding a column to the selected columns increases the total rows in the result. The query is using multiple subqueries declared using WITH. The join in the final query is a left join. Why is the row count getting impacted?

Comment: Are you using the `distinct` keyword?

Comment: yes. the select has a distinct keyword.

Answer (score 4):

The only way I can think of to increase the number of result rows by adding a column to the `SELECT` clause is when using `SELECT DISTINCT`.

`SELECT DISTINCT` removes duplicates from the results, so

```
col1   col2
a      b
a      b
a      c
a      c
```

becomes

```
col1   col2
a      b
a      c
```

When adding a column

```
col1   col2   col3
a      b      d
a      b      e
a      c      f
a      c      f
```

becomes

```
col1   col2   col3
a      b      d
a      b      e
a      c      f
```

for instance, which is one row more than before.